# Probleme with input select of Mdbootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

I have probleme is :

When I click on the input select (Name:example1)
i see the items in dropdown 
after when i click on other select (Name:example2) and the exemple1 still open, all input closed..

I know that you haven't understand me good, so this an video to illustrate my problem :
[Video to illustrate my probleme(video vimeo)](https://youtu.be/VgxlaoY7U3E)

Please how to fix this  ?

Comment: This is the normal/expected behavior of the select. Moreover, there is a grammar mistake it's "choisissez" not "choissisez".

Comment: @Myerffoeg, this is a problem, the normal behavior is when the select1 is opened and when i open the select2 the select1 he has to close and select2 he has to still open.. 
here the problem is select2 close also with select1, do not stay open

Comment: You made something to achieve this behavior with Mdbootstrap/JQuery?

Comment: No, i haven't modify anything